# Browser downloads index.php file and not opening page

Tags: apache, codeigniter, ubuntu

I just copied a working codeigniter directory structure to a new ubuntu EC2 instance.
I have setup apache and expected the browser page to just show up, but no!
The browser instead downloads codeigniter's index.php file.

Why is this happening?

All the files have user/group permissions as ubuntu:ubuntu. Has it got to do something with incorrect permissions?

Comment: that means there no .php handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with ec2 but it sounds like php isn't being loaded in apache. Try `sudo a2enmod php5` and restart apache.